# How to hide/show div when click on something with data binding?

Tags: angular, data-binding

Hey guys I try to implement a dynamic menu with data from my server. Because I Don't want to edit code each time we add new data in the database. So in the menu I've a first line with item and each  item have sub items I want to to make it inline. When I click on item in first line I want to show the menu of his sub items and when I re-click on another item on first menu show his sub items and hide the other sub items.

I 've created the first menu and generate a special sub menu for each item with ngif and ngfor. For the moment I set a style display:none property to theses sub nav.

```html
<div class="content card mt-4">
<!--first nav-->
                <ul *ngIf= "tabRes" class="nav justify-content-center">
                        <ng-container *ngFor = "let s of tabRes ">
<!--I want to use ClickMenu function to set the style property to the sub nav (but not implemented yet) -->
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" (click)="ClickMenu(s.nom)">{{s.nom}}</a></li>
                        </ng-container>
                </ul>
<!-- Sub nav by item of the firt nav -->
                <div *ngIf = "tabRes" >
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let x of tabRes">
                        <div *ngIf="x.child" style="display:none" [id]="x.nom" >
                                <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
<!-- sub nav of sub nav -->
                                        <li *ngFor = "let y of x.child" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">{{y.nom}
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        </ng-container>

                </div>


</div>
```

It's a little bit complex but I've to implement a menu like https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/menu/examples#nbmenuitem but inline. and sub items have to be shown when we click on the item in first menu line. I wanted to use data binding to do it but, I'm not able to bind property on element by checking his id for example. I mean if I add `[style]="display"` where `display` will be a property from my component that I'll be able to change with `menuClick()` function for example, it will be Apply to all sub menu I think and I Don't know how I'll be able to hide the other one if I use this solution. Can I do it like that ? And How ? Or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: I just want to know if it's a good way to process

Answer (score 0):

You need to add extra field in array. I don't know your ts but yes you need to add below code after getting data.

```
this.tabRes.forEach((tab)=>{
  tab.isExpandChild = false;
});
```

And your html is like

```
 <ul *ngIf= "tabRes" class="nav justify-content-center">
       <ng-container *ngFor = "let s of tabRes ">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" (click)="ClickMenu(s)">{{s.nom}}</a></li>
        <div *ngIf="s.isExpandChild " >
                     <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                        <li *ngFor = "let y of s.child" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">{{y.nom}}
                     </ul>
                </div>
       </ng-container>
</ul>
```

I am not sure about your HTML but yes i gave you idea about how to do it.

in your ts file

```
ClickMenu(s) {
  s.isExpandChild  = s.isExpandChild ? false : true;
}
```